# contactform with recaptcha v3 not working

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to set up a contact form in laravel with Recaptcha.

My problem is that when I add the data action, it prevents me from getting to my function.

So this is my form :

```
 <form action="{{action('App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@store')}}" method="POST" id="contactForm">
                @csrf
                <div class="flex flex-col p-10">
                    <label for="name" class="font-poppins text-sb-teagreen text-xl">{{__('Name')}}</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="border-2 border-sb-teagreen  p-2">
                    <label for="email" class="font-poppins text-sb-teagreen text-xl">{{__('Email')}}</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="border-2 border-sb-teagreen  p-2">
                    <label for="message" class="font-poppins text-sb-teagreen text-xl">{{__('Message')}}</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="border-2 border-sb-teagreen  p-2"></textarea>
                    <button
                        data-sitekey="{{ config('services.recaptcha.site_key') }}"
                        data-callback='onSubmit'
                        data-action="sendmail"
                        type="submit" class="g-recaptcha bg-sb-teagreen text-white font-poppins text-xl  p-2 mt-4">{{__('Send')}}</button>
                    @if(session('message'))
                        <div class="text-center bg-sb-teagreen text-white p-2 mb-2">{{ session('message') }}</div>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </form>
            @push('scripts')
                <script>
                    function onSubmit(token) {
                        document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
                    }
                </script>
            @endpush
```

**the routes**

```
Route::get('/contact', 'App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController@contact')->name('contact');
Route::post('/contactformulier', 'App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@store')->name('sendmail');
```

and then my controller :

```
  public function store(Request $request) {
    echo('test store function');
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required', new ReCaptcha]
    ]);
    $data = request()->all();
    Mail::to('**************')->send(new Contact($data));
    return redirect()->route('contact')->with('message', 'Thanks for your message. We\'ll be in touch.');
}
```

So when I remove the data-link I see my echo message and I can send a mail it all works. but when I add the google provide data options it prevents running it...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, it's an issue with your routes AND the name of the `data-action`.

Try changing the `data-action`'s name to `submit` (which is usually the default) along with the changes to the code I've mentioned here. And check if it works .

In your `web.php` file, change the store route to this:

```
Route::post('/contactformulier', [\App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::class, 'store'])
->name('contact.store');
```

Then in your form's action to this:

```
<form action="{{ route('contact.store') }}" method="POST" id="contactForm">
@csrf

<!-- Form fields here -->

  <button
     data-sitekey="{{ config('services.recaptcha.site_key') }}"
     data-callback='onSubmit'
     data-action="submit"
     type="submit" class="g-recaptcha">{{__('Send')}}
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried it but nothing happens

Comment: Is any error being returned in the browser's console? 

Also, did you import the Recaptcha V3 script into your `app.blade.php` file?

Comment: No i don't have any errors. and yes i put the script in my head tags.

Comment: Could you add `dd($request['g-recaptcha-response']);` into where your echo is in your store function, then submit the form and check if a string is being displayed, or if it is null?

Comment: Also, don't forget to have the `onSubmit` JavaScript function included in your question too. There is nothing wrong with that one.

Comment: Ah, in that case, chances are your Site Key for ReCaptcha is not being sent to the server. Assuming you placed your API keys in your .env file (and then linked them into `config.php` file), try running a `php artisan cache:clear` command to clear the env cache. 

And then check if the dd is the same. Again, don't forget to have the JavaScript `onSubmit` method.

Comment: When i remove the g-recaptcha class i can submit the form and the dd is then null. if i keep the class i can't submit my form.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `g-recaptcha` class is necessary for the Recaptcha. Most likely it's an issue with how Recaptcha was integrated into the site. You should make sure that the api keys are correct, making sure that there are no errors on the JS side of things and that the script for Recaptcha is correct as well. Aside that, everything seems fine and I'm not too sure what the issue is. Sorry :(